# Spring Boot Hibernate - Use of @OneToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Recognizing that there are a number of questions about this already, I can't see the problem for my specific case.  I have another instance of this in my application (which is working fine), and as far as I can tell I am mirroring the configuration.  In fact, when I run the application using `mvn: spring-boot:run`, everything works and all the data is found as expected.  However, when I try to run the tests for the application, any test that uses

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager em;
    ...
}
```

produces this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany
>   targeting an unmapped class:
>   com.utilities.domain.manufacturing.Machine.operators[com.humanresources.domain.MachineOperator]
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or
>   @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:
>   com.utilities.domain.manufacturing.Machine.operators[com.humanresources.domain.MachineOperator]

Admittedly, I don't have a great understanding of the configuration, but it doesn't make sense to me why one set of classes works but this does not.  Here are the classes (with just the pertinent parts):

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="humanresources.employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int employeeID;
    ...
    private List<MachineOperator> machines = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_employeeid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(View.SimpleEmployeeView.class)
    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    ...    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JsonView(View.EmployeeView.class)
    public List<MachineOperator> getMachines() {
        return machines;
    }

    public void setMachines(List<MachineOperator> machines) {
        this.machines = machines;
    }

    public void addMachine(Machine machine) {
        MachineOperator machineOperator = new MachineOperator(this, machine);
        this.machines.add(machineOperator);
        machine.getOperators().add(machineOperator);
    }

    public void removeCompany(Machine machine) {
        for (Iterator<MachineOperator> iterator = machines.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            MachineOperator machineOperator = iterator.next();

            if (machineOperator.getEmployee().equals(this) &&
                    machineOperator.getMachine().equals(machine)) {
                iterator.remove();
                machineOperator.getMachine().getOperators().remove(machineOperator);
                machineOperator.setEmployee(null);
                machineOperator.setMachine(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Machine**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="utilities.mnfg_machines")
public class Machine implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int machineID;
    ...
    private List<MachineOperator> operators = new ArrayList<>();

    public Machine() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_machineid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView({View.MachineView.class,View.DefaultMachineView.class})
    public int getMachineID() {
        return machineID;
    }

    public void setMachineID(int machineID) {
        this.machineID = machineID;
    }

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="machine",orphanRemoval=true)
    @JsonView({View.MachineView.class,View.DefaultMachineView.class})
    public List<MachineOperator> getOperators() {
        return operators;
    }

    public void setOperators(List<MachineOperator> operators) {
        this.operators = operators;
    }
}
```

**MachineOperator**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="humanresources.employee_machineoperators")
@IdClass(MachineOperatorID.class)
public class MachineOperator implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Employee employee;
    private Machine machine;
    private SkillLevel skillLevel;

    public MachineOperator() {}

    public MachineOperator(Employee employee, Machine machine) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    public MachineOperator(Employee employee, Machine machine, SkillLevel skillLevel) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.machine = machine;
        this.skillLevel = skillLevel;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_employeeid")
    @JsonView(View.SimpleEmployeeView.class)
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_machineid")
    public Machine getMachine() {
        return machine;
    }

    public void setMachine(Machine machine) {
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_skilllevelid")
    public SkillLevel getSkillLevel() {
        return skillLevel;
    }

    public void setSkillLevel(SkillLevel skillLevel) {
        this.skillLevel = skillLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(machine, employee);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;

        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        MachineOperator other = (MachineOperator) obj;
        return Objects.equals(machine, other.getMachine()) && Objects.equals(employee, other.getEmployee());
    }
}
```

**MachineOperatorID**

```
public class MachineOperatorID implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Employee employee;
    private Machine machine;

    public MachineOperatorID() {}

    public MachineOperatorID(Employee employee, Machine machine) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public Machine getMachine() {
        return machine;
    }

    public void setMachine(Machine machine) {
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 83 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.machine);
        hash = 83 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.employee);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final MachineOperatorID other = (MachineOperatorID) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.machine, other.machine)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.employee, other.employee)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas what is wrong, or is there a better way to get the same result?  (I want to be able to view an employee and see the machines they can operate, or view a machine and see all the employees which can operate it.)  I am using Spring Boot 2.0.3.  Thanks!

Comment: Is your app configured to scan entities in `com.humanresources.domain` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration

Comment: can you provide the console out when you start the app

Comment: @JeanMarois Yes, it is essentially configured to scan `com`. (I actually have `com.companyname` but had removed the company name for the post.)

Comment: @Keaz When I start the app, I just get the Spring ASCII art.  When I build the app, the only relevant output is what I have included above.

Comment: Can you show us how is the entity scan configured for the testing? Are you using the same main class ?

Comment: Is `MachineOperator` annotated with the correct `@Entity` annotation from `javax.persistence`? There is another one in hibernate, which is NOT a valid replacement. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Entity.html

Comment: @Dvorog I added all the annotations I am using for the test classes.

Comment: @JensSchauder Yes, I am only using the annotations from javax.persistence.

Comment: check if your code scans like `scanBasePackages = "com"` or `scanBasePackages = "com.**"`. If 1st variant, thet it will scan only `com` package directly and will not scan nested packages. Use second variant to scan nested packages under `com`

Comment: @Ulphat I'm not sure it works like that since I have quite a few nested packages, and it's worked fine before this.  But just to make sure, I tried with `.**`, and it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this occurs if your `javax.persistence`'s `@Entity` is not annotated or if the entities or not scanned. If you have tried the given options in comments, then please debug as follows:

- Enable **`DEBUG`** logging of org.hibernate in application.yaml/properties or log4j2.xml or any logging configuration.

Look for following or similar log : 
`o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : PersistenceUnitInfo
.
.
.
Managed classes names [
.
.
]`

By this, you will know the registered entities. Check if your entity is scanned from the path.

- Secondly if your entity is loaded, alter your `IdClass` **MachineOperatorID** to only have specific column fields and not object. From the hibernate specs, I quote:

> map multiple properties as @Id properties and declare an external
>   class to be the identifier type. This class, which needs to be
>   Serializable, is declared on the entity via the @IdClass annotation.
>   The identifier type must contain the same properties as the identifier
>   properties of the entity: each property name must be the same, its
>   type must be the same as well if the entity property is of a basic
>   type, **its type must be the type of the primary key of the associated
>   entity if the entity property is an association** (either a @OneToOne or
>   a @ManyToOne).

- If this is changeable code, please simplify your associations. Use `@Id` for individual columns and also use `@ManyToOne` associations separately on different field. Definitely your relationship can be simplified a lot.

Comment: The tip to find the `Managed classes names` was very helpful.  As it turned out, it was only getting entities from one package.  I would have thought the one package would have been fine for the given test, but apparently the `TestEntityManager` references/needs more than just what is in the test.  I added `@EntityScan("com.companyname")` to the test.  After that, everything shows up in the list of managed classes, and all tests now pass.  This doesn't fully make sense to me, but it does work.

Comment: Great then! :) What I did in my test was Autowired `entityManager` and created TestEntityManager myself. `new TestEntityManager(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory())`. This allowed scanned packages that the original entity manager had. And doesn't pollute and required `@DirtiesContext` if you manipulated transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the employee and machine objects from machineoperator class and replace it with MachineOperatorID instance in it. and create machine id and operator id as well with in MachineOperatorID class and annotate the instance with @ID that will resolve your problem and thats the correct way of doing things in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to edit your MachineOperatorID Class by changing the IDs to primitive types for example :

```
public class MachineOperatorID implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int employee;
private int machine; 

...
}
```

and see if it solves the problem. Or maybe you should consider this approach from docs:

> If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but
>   use an embedded database, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined
>   with @AutoConfigureTestDatabase rather than this annotation.